# Symfony2 Form Customization

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I want something like this:

```
<textarea rows="30" cols="70"  class="TextBox" style="height:100px;">
```

but inside my symfony2 aplication and not in the twig template
i tried this:

```
        $builder->add('history', 'textarea', array('label' => 'Nome' , 'max_length' => 1048576 , 'rows' = 30 , 'cols' = 70));
```

but i get "rows" and "cols" are not options...

in the twig i want something like this:

```
<label for="history">{{'form_anamnese_history'}}</label>
{{ form_widget(form.history) }}
```

to be a forum-post-like textbox!

Comment: Sizing elements is better done in your css.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use the `attr` array, as explained in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#attr):

```
$builder->add('history', 'textarea', array(
    'attr' => array('cols' => '5', 'rows' => '5'),
));
```

Answer (score 7):

You can set the display attributes for textarea in Twig rather than in the form:

```
{{ form_widget(edit_form.comment, { 'attr': { 
  'style' : 'width:525px', 
  'rows' : '4', 
  'cols' : '30' }} ) }}
```

As mentioned above, it is better practice to set this in CSS if possible however.

Comment: It's better to use rows and columns in my experience, as it matches up to the line height automatically.

Comment: Defining `rows` and `cols` in twig view is not working on symfony 2.8. It works only during form build as @juan pointed.

Comment: I would say this is the best answer because physical dimensions of a form widget should be a matter of particular twig template, and not of the form type class itself.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for problem in `Symfony 3`.

First:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
```

Second:
This is the code in Form:

```
->add('biografia', TextareaType::class, array(
      'label' => 'Como me identifico, Identifiquese utilizando un máximo de 500 caracteres',
      'attr' => array('class' => 'myclass')
      ))
```